# How to parallelise code to sort and sum a list in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have some code:

```
test<-therapyDF %>% group_by(therapyDF$prodcode) %>% summarize(count=n_distinct(therapyDF$patid))
```

that is designed to group all prodcode entries (drug) and then count how many patients (patid) have an instance of each drug. For example, the raw data is held in a dataframe similar to:

```
patid  prodcode
1       A
1       B
2       C
3       A
3       A
3       B
```

Thus, output will be:

```
A 2
B 2
C 1
```

Is there any way of parallelising this code? The real data is in excess of 100 million records and it's been more than 8 hours of running in serial. 
I'm struggling to adopt the *apply methodologies of R and the numerous R parallel packages. Splitting the original data frame would be a bit tricky, as the data is not very well organised (just how I got it) and it would require grouping an extracting by the $patid. I am running this on an 8 core intel Linux box.

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't look good. It could be like `test<-therapyDF %>% group_by(prodcode) %>% summarize(count=n_distinct(patid))` or like `df %>% group_by(prodcode) %>% unique() %>% count()`. You don't need `$` inside the pipe.

Comment: How many unique values of prodcode do you have in your dataset? Approximately.  From what you describe I suspect that the number of unique values in your prodcode variable is very large. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to parallelize a `group_by`-`summarize` with

```
summarize_par <- function(grouped_df, ...) {

  sizes <- attr(grouped_df, "group_sizes")
  ord <- order(sizes, decreasing = TRUE)

  one_group <- function(gdf, i, size) {

    size_i <- sizes[i]

    structure(
      gdf[attr(gdf, "indices")[[i]] + 1, ], 
      indices = list(0:(size_i - 1)),
      group_sizes = size_i,
      biggest_group_sizes = size_i,
      labels = attr(gdf, "labels")[i, , drop = FALSE]
    )
  }

  dots <- dplyr:::named_quos(...)
  res <- foreach(ic = ord) %dopar% {
    dplyr::summarise(one_group(grouped_df, ic), !!!dots)
  }

  do.call(rbind, res[match(seq_along(ord), ord)])
}
```

Test:

```
N  <- 2e7
therapyDF <- data.frame(patid = sample.int(N/2, size = N, replace = TRUE),
                        prodcode = sample(LETTERS, size = N, replace = TRUE))
library(dplyr)
system.time(true <- therapyDF %>% 
              group_by(prodcode) %>% 
              summarize(count=n_distinct(patid)))

library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
registerDoParallel(cl <- makeForkCluster(detectCores() / 2))

system.time(test <- therapyDF %>% 
              group_by(prodcode) %>% 
              summarize_par(count=n_distinct(patid)))
all.equal(true$count, test$count)

stopCluster(cl)
```

I get:

- sequential: 8.228
- parallel with 2 cores: 6.525

Here, my computer has not a lot of cores neither a lot of memory. 
You can expect better results with a better computer.

---

There is a performance issue with `n_distinct` at the moment (see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/977). **You should use `length(unique(patid))` instead of `n_distinct(patid)` to speed things up.**

Answer (score 1):

You should give `data.table` a try:

```
N  <- 1e8
therapyDF <- data.frame(patid = sample.int(N/2, size = N, replace = TRUE),
                        prodcode = sample(LETTERS, size = N, replace = TRUE))
library(dplyr)
system.time(therapyDF %>% 
  group_by(prodcode) %>% 
  summarize(count=n_distinct(patid)))
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>      36.939       1.196      38.136

library(data.table)
setDT(therapyDF)
system.time(therapyDF[, .(count = uniqueN(patid)), by = prodcode])
#>        User      System verstrichen 
#>       5.727       0.116       5.843
```

It uses OpenMP for parallel processing.

Comment: Seems like the performance problem is not with dplyr but with `n_distinct`?

Comment: @F.Privé I don‘t know where the performance difference comes from exactly, but it is quite common that `data.table` is very fast.

Comment: Try using `uniqueN` instead of `n_distinct` in the `summarize`.

Comment: @F.Privé Ok. But that is still data.table vs dplyr, as these functions are provided by those packages.

Comment: There is a problem with `n_distinct` at the moment (see https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/977). Using `length(unique(patid))` is enough to speed things up.